# DNAT port range with different internal port range with Iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, linux-networking

The standard way of DNATing a single port to a different port on an internal network is something like that:

`ip(6)tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wan0 -p tcp --dport 80 --to-destination 10.0.0.1:8080`

If you need a port range you can use `-m multiport` together with `--dports` like that:

`ip(6)tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wan0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 1000:2000 --to-destination 10.0.0.1`

Now what I want to know if you can combine the two techniques to map a port range (for example 1000-2000) to a different one of the same size (for example 12000-13000). Is that possible with Iptables using a kernel no later than Linux 4.1?

Comment: Note, you don't need `-m multiport`; `--dports` is happy to take a range such as `12000:13000`, `multiport` is needed for a comma-separated list, eg `-m multiport --dports 25,465,587`.  I don't have an answer to your main question, though; sorry.  And [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23652154/907628) suggests it can't be done.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll check with  the guys working on Netfilter if something like that can be implemented in Linux. I leave this open until I have a definite answer.

Answer (score 14):

To answer your question, **yes**.

I ran a sample rule on my Debian box...

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i xenbr0 -p tcp --dport 64000:65000 -j DNAT --to 172.16.10.10:61000-62000
```

... which produced no output, indicating success. I'm running kernel `3.16.0-4-amd64`.

Checking the NAT rule via `iptables -t nat -vnL PREROUTING`, I see the rule is listed...

```
DNAT       tcp  --  xenbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:64000:65000 to:172.16.10.10:61000-62000
```

MadHatter is correct, you do not need `-m multiport` for port ranges, only for comma-separated lists of ports. The `:` is needed in order to specify port ranges for the `--dport` option, but a `-` is needed in order to specify port ranges in the `DNAT` target.

How well this rule will work in practice I cannot say, but theoretically it should accomplish your goal.

More information on `DNAT` target can be found [here](http://www.iptables.info/en/iptables-targets-and-jumps.html#DNATTARGET).

Hope this helps.