# Use iptables to port forward multiple ports

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I have services running on VPS A(1.1.1.1) on ports 30000-32000.

I would like to have VPS B(2.2.2.2) to port forward them to 20000- 22000.

(You may take a look at the demo graph link below to understand what I would like to achieve :D )

[Forward to different ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STFwn.png)

I used the command below to set up iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 20000:22000 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:30000-32000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 1.1.1.1 --dport 30000:32000 -j SNAT --to-source 2.2.2.2
20000:22000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 20000:22000 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:30000-32000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -d 1.1.1.1 --dport 30000:32000 -j SNAT --to-source 2.2.2.2
20000:22000
```

After some tests, I find that it seems that only port 20000 was forwarding the original server's port 30000.
However, other ports are not working.

I checked 4 things below:
1. VPS A (1.1.1.1)'s service
Service running on ports 30000 - 32000 are fully functional

2. VPS B port forwarding setting
   Upon checking sysctl on VPS B, ipv4 forwarding is enabled.

(i.e. `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`)

3. VPS B's iptable setting. It looks fine to me.
   You may click on the link below for exact setting.

[iptables setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wZYn.png)

4. I also tried to do a normal multiple port forwarding from VPS A to VPS B
   (i.e. VPS A (30000-32000) >> VPS B (30000-32000))

(You may take a look at the demo graph link below for what I would like to achieve :D )

Everything is working fine.

I really have no idea how to achieve it.
Any help is appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/729810/dnat-port-range-with-different-internal-port-range-with-iptables

Comment: @Appleoddity Apparently it's not a duplicate. I know this is totally possible and have the command above in order to to achieve it, but it's not working properly for some unknown reasons.
Also, in the link you provided, that guys say:" I leave this open until I have a definite answer".

Answer (score 6):

You need to change iptables rules. Your DNAT rule doesn't filter destination IP address for incoming traffic from users. Your SNAT rule doesn't filter source IP address  and source port 30000:32000 range for incoming traffic from A server. You need on B server:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 2.2.2.2 --dport 20000:22000 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:30000-32000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 1.1.1.1 --sport 30000:32000 -j SNAT --to-source 2.2.2.2:20000:22000

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 2.2.2.2 --dport 20000:22000 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:30000-32000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -s 1.1.1.1 --sport 30000:32000 -j SNAT --to-source 2.2.2.2:20000:22000
```